# Nav drawer distorting title bar

Tags: html, css

So for giggles I was trying to figure out how to make one of these drawer sliders and I got most of it figured out except that when the hamburger menu is toggled the title bar is moved over resulting in some weird distortion of the hamburger menu.

What I'm looking for is when the hamburger menu is clicked the navbar slides out from off the screen to its designated width on top of the entire page. In no way should it move the page around it.

Of course the alternative is to have it move the entire page over as it extends...but I'd like to avoid that if I can.

HTML

```
 <body>
      <input type="checkbox" id="nav_drawer" name="" value="">
      <div id="wrapper">
        <label for="nav_drawer" class="nav_drawer_toggle">&#x2261;</label>

<header class="logo"><h1><a id="nav_logo" href="/index.php">This is my placeholder Title</a></h1></header>

<nav class="navigation">
   <ul>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">4</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">5</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">6</a></li>                
   </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

html,body{
   font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
   background-color: black;
   color: white;
}

#wrapper{
   margin: 0 auto;
   min-width: 320px;
   max-width: 1600px;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 0;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
   color:#FEBC11;
   text-align: center;
}

header #nav_logo{
   border-bottom: none; 
   background-color: transparent;
   text-decoration: none;
   color:#FEBC11;
}

header.logo h1{
   text-align: left;
   padding-left: .5rem; 
   font-size: 1rem;
   padding-bottom: 1rem;
   padding-top: 1rem;
   background-color: #333;
}

.logo{
   position: relative;
   z-index: 0;
}

.navigation{
   position:fixed;
   top: 3.25rem;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: -190px;
   z-index: 0;
   background-color: white;
   transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.navigation li{
   width: 10rem; 
}

.navigation li .nav_link{
   display: block;
   color: white;
   background-color: blue;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: .5rem;
   border-bottom: 1px solid red;
   text-align: center;
}

.navigation li a:hover{
   color: red;
}

.navigation li a.current{
   background-color: pink;
}

#nav_drawer{
   display: none;
}

#nav_drawer:checked + #wrapper .navigation{
   left: 0px;
}

#nav_drawer:checked + #wrapper .nav_drawer_toggle
{
   left: 200px;
}

#nav_drawer:checked + #wrapper .logo{
   padding-left: 180px;
}

.nav_drawer_toggle{
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   background: none;
   border: 0;
   color: white;
   font-weight: bold;
   cursor: pointer;
   margin-top: .4rem;
   margin-right: 1rem;
   font-size: 2rem;
   z-index: 1; 
}

.nav_drawer_toggle:hover{
   color:#FEBC11;
}
```

And here's a jsfiddle to demonstrate what I mean. Press the hamburger icon and you should see what I'm referring to.

https://jsfiddle.net/qbqthjwm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this two properties and you will have the header with 100% of the width of the screen and the hamburger on the right side when you toggle it.

```
#nav_drawer:checked + #wrapper .nav_drawer_toggle
{
   left: 200px;
}

#nav_drawer:checked + #wrapper .logo{
   padding-left: 180px;
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qbqthjwm/1/).